# Understanding Actions and UriQuery

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been given a task at work and as an intern everything is new haha. I have been asked to do the following:

```
//To test this you will need to update the code CoreModuleDesktop.cs.
this.NavManager.RegisterCommonActionItem("History Audit Log", "AuditLog", 110,
                    new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Core;component/Resources/maintenance.png")),
                    new Action(() => _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(Views.HistoryAuditLogView).FullName)));

//The part inside the action will need to be changed to look something like this 
//where you specify the parameters.  Then you can pull them out OnNavigateTo method
//like in the ServiceOrderMaintenanceViewModel.  For this step just pass in the 
//Table and Key ID, leave the connection string hard coded.

IRegionManager regionManager = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IRegionManager>();
UriQuery query = new UriQuery();

query.Add("AccountID", accountID.ToString());
query.Add("ServiceOrderID", serviceOrderID.ToString());

regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, new Uri(typeof(ServiceOrderMaintenanceView).FullName + query.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

What are they meaning the part inside of the Action? And how in the world is that query provided going to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [UriQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431576(v=pandp.40).aspx) is just a simple helper class to generate [HTML query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inside the Action" is `<here>`:

```
new Action(() => <here> );
```

In order to put multiple lines inside the `Action` you need to define a block with curly braces `{}`:

```
new Action(() => 
    {
        // this is
        // a couple of lines
        // of code to modify
    });
```

Hope this helps you get started.  For some background about how `Action` works in C# here is [the msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I just did not understand the syntax for this sort of thing.